# Splitting Rows in csv on several header rows

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am very new to python, so please be gentle.

I have a .csv file, reported to me in this format, so I cannot do much about it:

```
ClientAccountID   AccountAlias   CurrencyPrimary    FromDate
         SomeID      SomeAlias          SomeCurr    SomeDate
        OtherID     OtherAlias         OtherCurr   OtherDate
ClientAccountID   AccountAlias   CurrencyPrimary    AssetClass
         SomeID      SomeAlias          SomeCurr     SomeClass
        OtherID     OtherAlias         OtherCurr     OtherDate
      AnotherID   AnotherAlias       AnotherCurr   AnotherDate
```

I am using the csv package in python, so i have:

```
with open(theFile, 'rb') as csvfile:
    theReader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
```

Which, as I understand it, creates the dictionary 'theReader'. How do I subset this dictionary, into several dictionaries, splitting them by the header rows in the original csv file? Is there a simple, elegant, non-loop way to create a list of dictionaries (or even a dictionary of dictionaries, with account IDs as keys)?  Does that make sense?

Oh. Please note the header rows are not equivalent, but the header rows will always begin with 'ClientAccountID'.

Thanks to @ codie, I am now using the following to split the csv into several dicts, based on using the '\t' delimiter.

```
with open(theFile, 'rb') as csvfile:
    theReader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter = '\t')
```

However, I now get the entire header row as a key, and each other row as a value. How do I further split this up?

Thanks to @Benjamin Hodgson below, I have the following:

```
from csv import DictReader
from io import BytesIO

stringios = []

with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    stringio = None
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('ClientAccountID'):
            if stringio is not None:
                stringios.append(stringio)
            stringio = BytesIO()
        stringio.write(line)
        stringio.write("\n")
    stringios.append(stringio)

data = [list(DictReader(x.getvalue(), delimiter=',')) for x in stringios]
```

If I print the first item in stringios, I get what I would expect. It looks like a single csv. However, if I print the first item in data, using below, i get something odd:

```
for row in data[0]:
    print row
```

It returns:

```
{'C':'U'}
{'C':'S'}
{'C':'D'}
...
```

So it appears it is splitting every character, instead of using the comma delimiter.

Comment: use a tab delimiter, `(\t)` not a comma delimiter

Comment: Oh. How simple. How do I then create the sub-dictionaries?

Comment: `for row in theReader: do something()` where row is a dict of values in the given row. Python does all the magic under the covers for you.

Comment: You need to present a few actual lines from the csv files to allow us to give you an proper answer. If the case is that you have a csv file with multiple different id's in blocks of three (or seven) lines, then you need to do a little bit of magic when reading the file. The current example is ambigous...

Comment: I don't think you need any more info. To be honest, its not information I would be willing to share. If i had one header row, I would simply read it in with DictReader, with a comma for a delimiter, and I would have the structure I want. However, there are several stacked datasets, each with a different set of headers.

Comment: @cobie I am not sure how to split the new dict. If I use the tab as a delimiter, I now have a dict which has a whole dataset as a key, if that makes sense. what I would expect to be the first dict is actually a key now. Should I use the usual Reader, instead of the DictReader? How would that work?

Comment: You need to make up some fake data to better know what the format is. Take the first 10 lines or something and obfuscate the data.

Comment: That's exactly what I did above... Is there a way to post a file here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, you have a single CSV file which contains multiple tables. Tables are delimited by header rows which always begin with the string `"ClientAccountID"`.

So the job is to read the CSV file into a list of lists-of-dictionaries. Each entry in the list corresponds to one of the tables in your CSV file.

Here's how I'd do it:

1. Break up the single CSV file with multiple tables into multiple files each with a single table. (These files could be in-memory.) Do this by looking for lines which start with `"ClientAccountID"`.
2. Read each of these files into a list of dictionaries using a `DictReader`.

Here's some code to read the file into a list of [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO)s. (A `StringIO` is an in-memory file. It works by wrapping a string up into a file-like interface).

```
from csv import DictReader
from io import StringIO

stringios = []

with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    stringio = None
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('ClientAccountID'):
            if stringio is not None:
                stringio.seek(0)
                stringios.append(stringio)
            stringio = StringIO()
        stringio.write(line)
        stringio.write("\n")
    stringio.seek(0)
    stringios.append(stringio)
```

If we encounter a line starting with `'ClientAccountID'`, we put the current `StringIO` into the list and start writing to a new one. When you've finished, remember to add the last one to the list too.
Don't forget (as I did, in an earlier version of this answer) to rewind the `StringIO` after you've written to it using `stringio.seek(0)`.

Now it's straightforward to loop over the `StringIO`s to get a table of dictionaries.

```
data = [list(DictReader(x, delimiter='\t')) for x in stringios]
```

For each file-like object in the list `stringios`, create a `DictReader` and read it into a list.

It's not too hard to modify this approach if your data is too big to fit into memory. Use generators instead of lists and do the processing line-by-line.

Comment: I am getting an error: stringio.write(line) TypeError: unicode argument expected, got 'str'

And yes, you understood perfectly what I am trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: This answer is Python 3 code. I'm guessing you're on 2.7, based on that error message. Try changing `StringIO` to `BytesIO`.

Comment: Yes, I am using 2.7. That information is probably relevant... Apologies. Still running into problems, as it appears to work, but 'data' is empty when it completes. I am working through it.

Comment: Suggests that there aren't any lines which start with `'ClientAccountID'`. Is there some whitespace at the start of the line? If so try `line.strip().startswith('ClientAccountID')` instead of `line.startswith(...)`. (Also, I just spotted and fixed a bug in the answer ;)

Comment: Sorry - just updated. It looks like the delimiter is not being recognized? Or it is splitting at every character, instead of at the commas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93366/discussion-between-benjamin-hodgson-and-lukehawk).

Answer (score 1):

If your data was not comma or tab delimited you could use `str.split`, you can combine it with `itertools.groupby` to delimit the headers and rows:

```
from itertools import groupby, izip, imap

with open("test.txt") as f:
    grps, data = groupby(imap(str.split, f), lambda x: x[0] == "ClientAccountID"), []
    for k, v in grps:
        if k:
            names = next(v)
            vals = izip(*next(grps)[1])
            data.append(dict(izip(names, vals)))

from pprint import pprint as pp

pp(data)
```

Output:

```
[{'AccountAlias': ('SomeAlias', 'OtherAlias'),
  'ClientAccountID': ('SomeID', 'OtherID'),
  'CurrencyPrimary': ('SomeCurr', 'OtherCurr'),
  'FromDate': ('SomeDate', 'OtherDate')},
 {'AccountAlias': ('SomeAlias', 'OtherAlias', 'AnotherAlias'),
  'AssetClass': ('SomeClass', 'OtherDate', 'AnotherDate'),
  'ClientAccountID': ('SomeID', 'OtherID', 'AnotherID'),
  'CurrencyPrimary': ('SomeCurr', 'OtherCurr', 'AnotherCurr')}]
```

If it is tab delimited just change one line:

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    grps, data = groupby(csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t"), lambda x: x[0] == "ClientAccountID"), []
    for k, v in grps:
        if k:
            names = next(v)
            vals = izip(*next(grps)[1])
            data.append(dict(izip(names, vals)))
```

Comment: This is nice. I did not know about this lambda thing, but it is very useful. Also, could you use str.split in the second as well? Is there not a way to pass a different delimiter (\t) to it?

Comment: Also, looking at the documentation for imap, it says  imap(function, *iterables), implying that the file f is iterable? I am new to python, and I am just curious, but when passing a file, its interpreted as a set of iterable lines? If so, you iterate the lines, str.split them, then group them by lines whos first term is ClientAccountID? I think I understand it correctly, but it just seems... unusual (?) that the file is just an iterable set of lines? Or is that (fairly) normal? 
Thanks for this!

Comment: @lukehawk, you can pass whatever delimiter you want but in the map example you would need to use `map(lambda x: x.split("whatever")`, we can pass `str.split` because it is callable so we don't need a lambda, yes a file object returns it's own iterator so you will get a line at a time as you iterate over it, the imap splits the each line on any whitespace, then each time we `if k` is True we have a line with the first column == "ClientAccountID" so we call next on the groupby object to get all the lines either up to the next row with "ClientAccountID" or the end of the file