# How to split a CSV with multiple headers with Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a report from some software we use for planning/modeling purposes. The CSV that is generated by the program is essentially 4 reports with their own unique headers in one long csv file. The gap between the sections is different every time depending on how long our simulation is. I've been practicing Python for a bit and realized I really should automate the reformat of this data.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to parse the data between the known headers and write the rows in between to individual CSV files. I've figured out how to open and read/write the CSV files by importing csv.

The headers for each section of the report are always the same, just the number of rows between them will be different each time so I can't just tell the CSV to split every couple hundred/thousand rows. I feel like a while loop might be the ticket but I'm happy to admit that I'm stuck!

The report reads as such:

*First Header*
`Index,WindowID,WindowStart,WindowEnd,SCID,PlanningStatus,TransmitDeadline,WindowAreaAquired,OrderAreaAcquired,ScansIncluded,ScanDuration,Cost,CameraOff`

(...) (X many lines of results)

*Second Header*

`Order Id,Occurrence Start,Occurrence End,Has Access,Fulfilled`

(...) (X many lines of results)

*Third Header*

`Fulfilled Order Ids,Fulfilled Order Targets,Original Area,Unfulfilled (at start),Order Area acquired (at end)`

(...) (results lines)

*Fourth Header*

`Order,Vehicle,Window ID,Start Time,Type,Mode,Device`

(...) Results for 4th section

Originally I was looking at the 2 other questions marked as duplicates of my question: [Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20293327/use-python-to-split-a-csv-file-with-multiple-headers) & [Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33306681/splitting-rows-in-csv-on-several-header-rows). 
However, both of these examples have headers that repeat, not unique. The code in Question 1 I think points me in the right direction but I'm trying to figure out the best way to tell the script to start over again once it reaches the next header line.

I bodged together some code which I don't think is correct:
    import csv
    from io import StringIO

```
outfile_name = "campaignout_%.csv"
out_num = 1

with open('campaignreport.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    csv_buffer = []

    for line in csvreader:
        if line.startswith("Index"):
            csv_buffer.append(row)
        elif line.startswith("Order Id"):
            with open(outfile_name % out_num, 'wb') as csvout:
                for b_row in csv_buffer:
                    csvout.writerow(b_row)
                out_num += 1
                csv_buffer = [row]
            csv_buffer = []
            csv_buffer.append(row)
        elif line.startswith("Fulfilled Order Ids"):
            with open(outfile_name % out_num, 'wb') as csvout:
                for b_row in csv_buffer:
                    csvout.writerow(b_row)
                out_num += 1
                csv_buffer = [row]
            csv_buffer = []
            csv_buffer.append(row)
        elif line.startswith("Order"):
            with open(outfile_name % out_num, 'wb') as csvout:
                for b_row in csv_buffer:
                    csvout.writerow(b_row)
                out_num += 1
                csv_buffer = [row]
            csv_buffer = []
            csv_buffer.append(row)
        else:
            with open(outfile_name % out_num, 'wb') as csvout:
                for b_row in csv_buffer:
                    csvout.writerow(b_row)
                out_num += 1
                csv_buffer = [row]
```

Comment: Have you tried any code?

Comment: Are the headers identical for all 4 reports?

Comment: If threes a blank like between the sections, you could look for that and break the loop, and then have another loop for the next section. if not, maybe you can recognise the header of the next section, and break your loop when you see it?

Comment: Please show us a report including the headers. To save space, leave out some of the lines (other than headers) and put in an ellipse (...) where you have omitted lines.

Comment: Bill - added the headers.